# How to make button outline same as span outline on chromium in tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

The markup

```html
  <span class="outline">
    <button>a</button>
    <span>a</span>
  </span>
```

produces a non-rectangular outline on chromium ([tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/UFsKxOCAUx))

[image: letters "aa" with a black outline which is wider on the left letter]

Even more concerningly, it's a rectangle on firefox

[image: letters "aa" with a black rectangle outline]

What's happening and how do I stop it? I'd like it to be a rectangle on all browsers, I'm only using a button for accessibility inside my clickable span monster.

Answer (score 0):

Since the parent element is assuming a block display, maybe you need to set the child element as inline block, to take on the height of its parent. I edited the Play link and I think I got your desired result by doing this:

```
<div class="p-12">
  <span class="inline-block outline">
    <button>a</button>
    <span>a</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I think I need `inline`, I'm making these big trees of spans that need to render as text, and `inline-block` introduces line breaks

Comment: How about using inline-flex there?

Comment: also introduces line breaks. In practice I think I might just go with a span with`tabindex=0` etc., didn't expect a little bit of inline text button to cause such issues